# Sublime Text 3 не выводит ответ

Tags: python, sublime-text-3

Пробовал искать в гугле, говорят нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> и выбрать Python, но я уже это сделал, а результата нет. (Свой билд (не свой конечно) для вывода ответа пытался сделать, выводит ошибку.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй запустить код через командную строку, должно сработать

Comment: Это старый и рабочий способ, но мне важен быстрый результат (саблайм выбрал ради него). CTRL+B удобней.

Comment: На какой ОС проблема?

Comment: Windows 10 версия 20H2

Answer (score 2):

Выглядит как неправильная настройка билдинга. Решение – создать рабочую Build System :) Например так:

1. Открываем Sublime Text -> Tools -> Build System -> New Build System
2. Вставляем в открывшийся файл следующие строки, чтобы получилось вот так:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

3. Сохраняем файл с названием python3.sublime-build и не меняем путь предложенный редактором
4. Идем и ставим галочку Tools -> Build system -> python3

<sub>Источник: [GitHub Gist: simplesasha: Интеграция Python 3 в Sublime Text 3](https://gist.github.com/simplesasha/73005e8e08065d8c360dba09dc86626b)</sub>

Ещё можно не создавать новую, а отредактировать старую инструкцию. Найти файлы Саблаймовских Build System можно [по таким путям](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23790095/5308802):

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Windows: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`

Там же вы сможете посмотреть текущую конфигурацию и выяснить, почему она не работает.

Comment: К сожалению не сработало. Сделал этот билд, поставил его. Ошибку не выводит, но ответа тоже нет.

Comment: @Daskis
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\yourUserName\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
Указать абсолютный путь к python.exe
Ключ "-q" вместо "-i" для завершения процесса после выполнения